# Can a URL be added to PHP's open_basedir?

Tags: php, open-basedir

I'm facing an issue with PHP's `open_basedir` directive with relation to a composer package that I don't have control over, and use of a Google Font.

The package I'm using is `matthiasmullie/minify`, which uses `is_file()` during it's execution. One of the things it's trying to minify is a Google Font CSS file. The error message is coming from an `@font-face` segment which links to a src font file...

```
is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4.woff2) 
is not within the allowed path(s): ...
```

Disabling `open_basedir` is a common "solution" for people, but removing security features is not a solution.

I have a number of local paths specified for my resources, but I can't seem to find any documentation on whether I can specify a remote URL such as `https://fonts.gstatic.com` (without trailing slash to allow for all sub-dirs). Altering my routines to skip minify on the google fonts calls will be a PITA, so I'm hoping for a different solution.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or can you point to the documentation that might outline it's syntax if it differs or there are options or consequences of this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could extend the class and override the method that has the buggy behaviour.

Comment: It's a bug which was fixed in Feb 2018, see: https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify/issues/224

Comment: @Luuk I'm on their latest version but for some reason, the patch isn't catching the URL. That said, I'm seeing an extra slash in the error code I posted here, I'm guessing that's the issue, so I now have to figure out where that's coming from.